# Speeding up Loop / Match - Code runs very slow

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, match

I have a code that matches a cell value in Column C on Sheet1 to a pivot table on Sheet3 and then copies certain columns over.

- Code will check how many entries there are on Sheet1 that need to be checked
- Loop 2: For every value in Column C/Sheet1 with a match in Column A on Sheet 2 it will then copy over the corresponding data from Column B,C,D,E.
- Since there are multiple matches possible by value/Sheet I am limiting the data pull to three matches (three loops in the code). To achieve that I am increasing i +1 or i+2 to get the next row in the pivot table.

The table on Sheet 2 is sometimes 10,000+ rows and excel crashes.

Does anyone have an idea how to speed up the loop codes (Loop2,3,4 are the same) to make it less work intensive e.g. array possibly? They are causing the lock up since I think the code keeps running up and down column A.

```
  Set sheet3 = Sheets("OrbitPivotTable")
  CellChanged = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value + 1

  LastRow = sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  LastData = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
'Loop1
    
  For i = 1 To LastRow

   If Sheet1.Range("C" & CellChanged).Value = "" Then GoTo Nextstep2
      
      If Sheet1.Range("C" & CellChanged).Value = sheet3.Range("A" & i) Then
         Sheet1.Range("H" & CellChanged).Value = sheet3.Range("B" & i).Value 'Customer
         Sheet1.Range("I" & CellChanged).Value = sheet3.Range("C" & i).Value 'Rate Val start
         Sheet1.Range("J" & CellChanged).Value = sheet3.Range("D" & i).Value 'ATA All in
         Sheet1.Range("K" & CellChanged).Value = sheet3.Range("E" & i).Value 'Special Remarks

          Found = True
        End If
         If Found = True Or i = LastRow Then
            If CellChanged = LastData Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If Found = True Then
                Found = False
Nextstep2:
                CellChanged = CellChanged + 1
            End If
            i = 0
        End If
    Next i
    
'Loop2
```

etc....

[Excel File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GlZWLFQeCfEDv1-EVuMCp6_WzQVyDW8E/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you use `Application.Match()` to locate the matches on each sheet it will be faster than looping.  I would avoid worksheet variable names like "Sheet1" etc because they match the default worksheet codenames assigned by Excel - it's not wrong but could be confusing. Better to use variable names corresponding to the actual sheet purpose  - `wsComp`, `wsCPK` etc. FYI if you post less code you're more likely to get responses.  That's a lot to go through.

Comment: ok thanks for the feedback. I read on other posts that not enough code was posted. Let me slim down my request above and will try application.match.

Comment: @TimWilliams do i need to convert all sheet1.range lanes to application.match or just the first lane in the loop where the match is located? changed the code to this: `If Application.Match(Sheet1.Range("C" & CellChanged).Value, Sheet2.Range("A" & i), 0) Then` Do i need to keep .Range?

Comment: Is there any chance you can share the workbook or at least some screenshots?  I'm having problems figuring out your exact process - eg typically it's not a good idea to modify a `For` loop counter inside the loop, so setting` i=0` is odd.  You can just use `Exit For` to get out of the loop if that's what you want to do.

Comment: i = 0 'if match was found. Check will start again in Row 1 and continue until next match is found. It seems like double "effort"

Comment: Where is the code I presented wrong? I'm curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might have misunderstood the process in the file you shared, but this should be faster (and much less code overall).

I put the pivot table lookup in a loop, switched to `Match()`, and reduced the number of read/writes using arrays where possible.

**EDITED** to fix an embarrassing bug where I forgot to adjust the `Match()` result `m` to account for the starting row of the range I run match() against...

```vba
Sub HB_IPT_Rate_Check()

    Dim wsReport As Worksheet, wsCPK As Worksheet, wsOrbitPivot As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, rwReport As Range, lastPivotRow As Long
    Dim ata, m, numMatches As Long, matchFrom As Long, matchRow As Long
    
    Set wsReport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Comparison Report")
    Set wsCPK = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CPK")
    Set wsOrbitPivot = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OrbitPivotTable")
    
    'loop over the rows in the report sheet
    For Each c In wsReport.Range("C3", wsReport.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Cells
        
        ata = c.Value 'read this once....
        Set rwReport = c.EntireRow
        
        '1st Database Match "CPK"
        m = Application.Match(ata, wsCPK.Columns("A"), 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            With wsCPK.Rows(m)
                rwReport.Columns("D").Resize(1, 4).Value = _
                   Array(.Columns("B").Value, .Columns("C").Value, _
                         .Columns("F").Value, .Columns("H").Value)
                'Sum of HB CWGT (KG),Sum of MB CWGT (KG),Achiev CPK,Density
            End With
        Else
            'no match...
        End If
        
        '2nd Database Match "Orbit"
        lastPivotRow = wsOrbitPivot.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        numMatches = 0  'reset match count
        matchFrom = 2
        m = Application.Match(ata, wsOrbitPivot.Range("A" & matchFrom & ":A" & lastPivotRow), 0)
        'keep going while we still have a match and we've not reached the max result count
        Do While Not IsError(m) And numMatches < 3
            numMatches = numMatches + 1
            matchRow = matchFrom + (m - 1) 'adjust the matched row index according to where we started looking...
            
            'sanity check
            Debug.Print "Matched " & ata & " on row " & matchRow
            
            rwReport.Columns("H").Offset(0, (numMatches - 1) * 4).Resize(1, 4).Value = _
                                    wsOrbitPivot.Cells(matchRow, "B").Resize(1, 4).Value
            
            'find the next match if any, starting below the last match
            matchFrom = matchRow + 1
            m = Application.Match(ata, wsOrbitPivot.Range("A" & matchFrom & ":A" & lastPivotRow), 0)
        Loop
    Next c 'next report row
    
  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Use Dictionary to set row and column number.
2. Data is assigned to fit rows and columns in a virtual array.

---

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws(1 To 4) As Worksheet
    Dim DicR As Object  ' Dictionary
    Dim DicC As Object  ' Dictionary
    Dim vDB, arr()
    Dim s As String
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, j As Integer
    Dim r As Long, c As Integer
    
    Set Ws(1) = Sheets("Comparison Report")
    Set Ws(2) = Sheets("CPK")
    Set Ws(3) = Sheets("OrbitPivotTable")
    Set Ws(4) = Sheets("Orbit")
    
    'Row index dictionary
    Set DicR = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'New Scripting.Dictionary
    'Column index dictionary
    Set DicC = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") ' New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    vDB = Ws(1).UsedRange
    
    For i = 3 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        s = vDB(i, 3)
        If s <> "" Then
            If DicR.Exists(s) Then
               'DicC(s) = DicC(s) + 1
            Else
                n = n + 1
                DicR.Add s, n 'row index
                DicC.Add s, 0 'column index
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    'Create an array of virtual tables based on the number of dictionaries.
    'Since the number of columns cannot be predicted, a specific number of 1000 was entered.
    'in my test, number 100 is too small
    ReDim arr(1 To DicR.Count, 1 To 1000)
    
    For j = 2 To 4
        vDB = Ws(j).Range("a1").CurrentRegion
        For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
            s = vDB(i, 1)
            If DicR.Exists(s) Then
                r = DicR(s)
                c = DicC(s) * 4 + 1
                DicC(s) = DicC(s) + 1
                arr(r, c) = vDB(i, 2)
                arr(r, c + 1) = vDB(i, 3)
                arr(r, c + 2) = vDB(i, 4)
                arr(r, c + 3) = vDB(i, 5)
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
    With Ws(1)
        .Range("d3").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
    End With
End Sub
```

### Result image

[image]

Comment: thanks. DY.Lee your option works as well.